# BSOD when enabling Virtual Machine Platform in combination with vt-d

Tags: virtualization, bsod, wsl2, vt-d, wslg

I did a new install of windows 11 on my laptop. Everything was fine until I ran "wsl --install"
Got the BSOD with INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE. After I disable VT for Direct I/O in BIOS my device boots again.

```
Version     22H2 
OS build    22621.525 
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22634.1000.0
```

My hardware specs are the following:

```
Processor       Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.59 GHz
Installed RAM   32,0 GB (31,7 GB usable)
```

I have found several Github threads like [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4784). I have tried out all (but one) of the suggested solutions but none of them get me to run VMP and vt-d at the same time. I will be trying out the last one, which is updating the network driver to its default windows 11 version but I still need some feedback from the user who suggested this.

I've been struggling with this for the past week now and am starting to get a little desperate. I'm not willing to concede just yet though.

So, correct me if I'm wrong but I can run WSL2 and docker with vt-d disabled, but I won't be able to take advantage of WSLg, right? I really hope I can resolve this and will eventually be able to run both VMP and vt-d because the reason I wanted to switch to Windows 11 was to use WSLg. Before having this struggle, I was struggling to get a decent setup running with an Xserver and WSLg looked like the solution for this.

More concrete, the things I have tried are:

1. keeping vt-d enabled before doing wsl --install and updating windows and drivers one by one to see if there was a conflict between a driver and vt-d. This way I narrowed it down to VMP (and probably Hypervisor) because I also go into BSOD when only turning on Hyper-V and vt-d together.
2. doing a gradual install of every needed piece for WSL2. But after installing (or enabling VMP) I also get a BSOD
3. starting with WSL1 and upgrading to WSL2
4. running WSL without vt-d. Which works but when I install something inside my Distro I don't get a Windows link to the Linux GUI so I think this is why I need vt-d to fully use WSL2 and WSLg
5. Switch my SATA operations from "Raid On" to "AHCI" as per this forum [suggestion](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/enabled-vd-t-now-there-is-an-inaccessible_boot_device-error.2604390/)
6. Make sure that BIOS is up to date
7. Been on constant dell support chat for the past 4 days. They just blame Microsoft. Could well be because this happens with multiple manufacturers

Comment: You should be able to enable VT-d and Hyper-V simultaneously. Try updating BIOS (UEFI) and see if that corrects the issue.

Comment: Sadly, the BIOS was already up to date. This is not the issue.

Comment: Contact Support at the company that manufactured the computer.  There is not much left that you can do.

Comment: I have been on support chat with Dell for the past 4 days. They just make me run in circles, asking me the same questions over and over again and just point fingers at Microsoft. I get where they are coming from since the laptop runs with vt-d enabled. The problem only starts to emerge when VMP feature is enabled. I've also seen this come up for people with other brands of laptop.

Comment: As I said I am not sure about this. No issues with my machines (Lenovo)

Comment: “So, correct me if I'm wrong but I can run WSL2 and docker with vt-d disabled, but I won't be able to take advantage of WSLg, right?” - Incorrect; WSLg doesn’t require VT-d

Comment: @Ramhound, ok understood but then I don't understand why the apps installed in Ubuntu (WSL2) are not showing up as executables in Windows. I have installed PHPstorm and x11-apps in Ubuntu to test this out, but they are not picked up by Windows.